# Java: Use ObjectOutputStream without serializable

Tags: java, serialization, io, objectoutputstream

Sometimes, I want to use an `ObjectOutputStream` to write something to a file or sending a little image over the network. But `BufferedImage` and many other classes don't implement `java.io.Serializable` and then the Stream cancels writing. Is there a way avoid that?

Thanks, Martijn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Only objects that support the
>   java.io.Serializable interface can be
>   written to streams.

-- [ObjectOutputSteam docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)

However, you could avoid all this by using one of the classes in `javax.imageio`.  Specifically the [`ImageIO.write(RenderedImage, String, OutputStream)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)) method, because `BufferedImage` implements `RenderedImage`.  You can then read it back out with [`ImageIO.read(InputStream)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)), which returns a `BufferedImage`.

You'll probably want a different `OutputSteam` type, though.  In addition to the normal `OutputStream`s, there are several special [`ImageOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageOutputStream.html)s.

Edit: I missed this before:
To get a list of valid strings for the middle argument, you can call [`ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getWriterFormatNames())

Answer (score 5):

One way to deal with unserializable objects is simply skip them. You can extends ObjectOutputStream and implement replaceObject method that checks if object is serializable.

```
public class MyOOS extends ObjectOutputStream {
    public MyOOS(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
        enableReplaceObject(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object replaceObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
        if ((obj instanceof Serializable))
            return obj;
        System.err.println("Skipping serialization of "+obj);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. That's like saying, "I want to display an object as text, but don't know anything about how to convert it into a string."

The entire purpose of `Serializable` is to say "I know how to be serialized to a stream!" - if we didn't need it, we wouldn't have it.

Now if you have an object which implements `Serializable` but contains something which itself *doesn't* implement `Serializable`, but which you could work out some way of serializing by hand, you could always customize the serialization of the container object yourself.

Basically `ObjectOutputStream` is designed for Java's serialization framework. If you don't want to use the serialization framework, don't use `ObjectOutputStream`. Images in particular are likely to have their own "native format" which `ImageIO` can deal with (as R. Bemrose noted).

Answer (score 2):

Write an ObjectOutputStream subclass, call enableReplaceObject, and then override replaceObject(Object).  You probably also need a companion ObjectInputStream subclass does the same by overriding resolveObject(Object).

Answer (score 1):

It *may* be an option for uou to use a different serialization mechanism. [JBoss Serialization](http://jboss.org/serialization/) is a drop-in replacement for standard java.io serialization, although because the serialization format is different, both readers and writers need to use the same mechanism.

JBoss Serialization does not require classes to implement `java.io.Serializable`, however there's no guarantee that the objects will survive the process if they aren't explicitly Serializable.